# How to manage huge amount of files in shell?

Tags: shell, filesystems, python

> $ ls
>   ./dir_with_huge_amount_of_files/errors/

Suppose a directory is full of pictures with unix timestamps, I mean a lot measured in many GBs or even more. Shell-commands like `ls` will get overflow-style warnings because they are not designed to work with millions (or more) of pictures. How can I manage such huge amount of files? If, for example, I want to find the picture in the middle (according to the timestamp in the name and creation time), is there some file-system that offers a built-in search feature? Which commands would you use? I tried the comfortable `ls` and `find` with necessary flags but they were either very slow or generated warnings so I am thinking that either I need better file-system or db or something like that to pre-index the pictures. I basically need one array to which inodes of the photos should be placed in chronological order. How to do that? Later, metadata with unix-timestamps could be added.

**[Update]**

There is a serious flaw in current answers, people just post sort-of-answers without empirical tests. If they had tested their suggestions, they would probably fail. Hence, I created you a command-line tool by which you can create the sandbox to create the huge amount of files and test your suggestions like with 1e7 amount of files. It can take a long time to generate the files so be patient. If someone knows quicker way to do this, please edit the code. Type `python code.py --help` to get the help. Have fun!

**Usage Example to create a lot of dirred files**

```
$ ls ./data2
ls: ./data2: No such file or directory
$ python testFill.py -n 3 -d 7                                                 
$ tree data2/                                                                  
data2/
|-- 0
|   |-- 1302407302636973
|   |-- 1302407302638022
|   `-- 1302407302638829
|-- 1
|   |-- 1302407302639604
|   |-- 1302407302641652
|   `-- 1302407302642399
|-- 2
|   |-- 1302407302643158
|   |-- 1302407302645223
|   `-- 1302407302646026
|-- 3
|   |-- 1302407302646837
|   |-- 1302407302649110
|   `-- 1302407302649944
|-- 4
|   |-- 1302407302650771
|   |-- 1302407302652921
|   `-- 1302407302653685
|-- 5
|   |-- 1302407302654423
|   |-- 1302407302656352
|   `-- 1302407302656992
`-- 6
    |-- 1302407302657652
    |-- 1302407302659543
    `-- 1302407302660156

7 directories, 21 files
```

**Code testFill.py**

```
# Author: hhh
# License: ISC license

import os, math, time, optparse, sys

def createHugeAmountOfFiles(fileAmount, dirAmount):
   counter = 0
   DENSITY = 1e7
   dir = "./data/"

   do = dir+str(counter)+"/"
   while (os.path.exists(do)):
      counter = counter+1
      do = dir+str(counter)+"/"

   os.mkdir(do)

   for d in range(int(dirAmount)):
      for f in range(int(fileAmount)):
         timeIt = int(time.time()*1e6)
         if (not os.path.exists(do)):
            os.mkdir(do)

         if (timeIt % DENSITY == 0):
            counter = counter+1
            do = dir+str(counter)+"/"

            if (not os.path.exists(do)):
               os.mkdir(do)


         do = dir+str(counter)+"/"
         if(not os.path.exists(do)):
            os.mkdir(do)

         f = open(do+str(timeIt), 'w')
         f.write("Automatically created file to test Huge amount of files.")
         f.close()
      counter = counter +1


def ls(dir):
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./data/"+dir):
      print(files)

def rm(dir):
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./data/"+dir):
      for f in files:
         os.remove("./data/"+dir+"/"+f)


def parseCli():
   parser = optparse.OptionParser()
   parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                     help="Location to remove files only in ./Data.", metavar="FILE")
   parser.add_option("-n", "--number", dest="number",
                     help="Number of files to generate", metavar="NUMBER")
   parser.add_option("-r", "--remove", dest="remove",
                     help="Data -dir content to remove", metavar="NUMBER")
   parser.add_option("-d", "--dir", dest="dir",
                     help="Amount of dirs to generate", metavar="NUMBER")
   parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                     action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                     help="don't print status messages to stdout")

   return parser.parse_args()

def main():
   (options, args) = parseCli()

   if (options.filename):
      ls(options.filename)
   if (options.number and options.dir):
      createHugeAmountOfFiles(options.number, options.dir)
   if (options.remove):
      rm(options.remove)


main()
```

Comment: @hhh for dataset's on this scale a properly index-ed db is probably the only option

Comment: @xenoterracide: but even dbs must implement fast searching with something like arrays, db sounds an overkill. Source for picture-taking thing is here: https://github.com/fsphil/fswebcam. Perhaps, I could mod it a bit the time it saves the picture so I could append a line with inode-number&unix-time-stamp to file. Now not with the pictures but line, it would be much faster to search for pictures. Or even more easily, each time a picture is saved to a disk, I append a line to a file of its time-stamp. Round-around solution. But won't solve the problem with current pictures so question relevant.

Comment: @hhh what filesystem are you using? or doesn't that matter yet... ext does has some performance enhancing features which may not be on by default. Though even those probably won't deal on the scale you're talking. DB's are optimized for these things and have various indexing solutions to deal with them. for example a btree index is not just a simple array...

Comment: @xenoterracide: ext3, not sure either whether it matters. I think the solution I illustrated fixes the problem for future search problem but it does not help at all with current photos, it is very time-consuming to search it.

Comment: @hhh as root do `tune2fs -l /dev/<ext partition>` look to see if filesystem features include `dir_index` honestly though I doubt it helps much in this case. I don't know if things like nepomuk or whatever gnome has... have cli clients... but almost every solution is going to need a pregenerated index, which will take a while to run.

Comment: Do you have millions of files in a single directory?  If so you might consider splitting them by one or two-levels deep subdirs, based on first chars of the file name, e.g: `a/b/abcdef.jpg`

Comment: @alex: that is a good idea but what do you do when you have too large amount of dirs?

Comment: @hhh: with this approach you may only have up to about 256 directories on any given level, so for two levels of indirection you'll have up to 256*256=65536 directories in total (more, if Unicode in filenames is employed.)  Is that too large already for your filesystem?

Comment: @alex: of course not. The question is about managing huge amount of files and it really means, the scalability is a serious problem which I don't know how to address correctly, not just that many familiar shell commands fail so I am using Python like the added example code shows. I think the dir restriction can be circumvented by mounting new fs to the system every time space is used in one machine, any experience with that?

Comment: Why not just use full-blown database then?  Modern databases allow you to store arbitrary file content in a table column.  Adding an index to modification date column you can instantly search it.

Answer (score 4):

Try a different shell. I'd recommend trying [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) for instance, and see if it allows more parameters.

If I understand correctly, part of the filename, is a UNIX timestamp. It might be advisable, to divide the files into folders. If the date/time format is a UNIX epoch number, put chunks of fractions of that number, say 10000's, in a separate folder.

If an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamp is part of the filename, simply divide by year, month or day.

Comment: ls and find aren't builtins in either bash or zsh, so it's unclear how switching shells would help in this instance.

Comment: It's about shell expansion. If the shell can't expand the globbing, this might be the issue.

Comment: I made few tests running commands on about 1e6 files, ZSH faces the same problems: `"$ cp * Test/                                                                                 
ksh: cp: Argument list too long

% rm *
zsh: sure you want to delete all the files in /home/user/Downloads [yn]? y

zsh: argument list too long: rm 
% ls *
zsh: argument list too long: ls
"`. Sorry but I cannot see how this is related to the question -1 because it was so easy to test this, create just 1e6 files and run the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Would `locate` (and of course `updatedb`) be of any help to you?

Comment: `updatedb` uses `find`.

Comment: @dave1010, sure, but it does so in the background once in a while, so if it is acceptable to the OP to not necessarilly be up to date every minute, but maybe once a day, then schedule updatedb at a quiet hour (or schedule updatedb frequently but at a low priority, which is what it should be at anyway), then using locate is very quick to find what you want. So the key question is how up to date does the DB (or the index for any other such system) need to be.